# Ruby programming in Qt Framework

Tags: ruby, qt, frameworks

I need a GUI cross platform library to build a Ruby DB app via MySQL. In order to be more clear, i need something similar to [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/widgets-and-layouts.html) (Qt Widgets) especially the Advanced Widget part such as QTableView. I know that this could be done (programming in Qt Framework via C++ or Python) and there are many books written on Amazon! ([Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt and others](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html)).

Is there any similar support regarding Ruby in order to develop in Qt framework using Ruby instead of C++ or Python?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, support for GUI programming in ruby has waned over the years.

`wxRuby`: Alex Fenton used to maintain wxRuby, but no more (wx was always my first choice of GUI flavors in whatever language I was using), and hackers trashed the wxRuby wiki.

`Shoes`: When its creator Why disappeared, it sort of languished for awhile, then it was resurrected in different colors: Red Shoes, Green shoes.  But, it's not a full featured GUI toolkit, and I've generally been disappointed with its appearance on OSX.

`Tk/Tkinter`: It's part of the Ruby Standard Library.  The Tk docs also have examples in Ruby: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html

`Qt`: In the past, I've avoided Qt because of the restrictive licensing,  but I think the licensing has gotten more liberal over the years, and recently I had a play with it in python. As for Qt in ruby, I've used the Ruby Qt tutorial several times here: http://zetcode.com/gui/rubyqt/, but that's pretty old.  I don't remember there being any other Qt resources in ruby.

Also, beware: that `python Qt book` is also old. On amazon, it says the book was published in 2015, but amazon also says it's the 1st edition, and I know that book has been around a lot longer than that.  So, I looked it up, and the first edition was published in 2007.  I don't know why amazon is listing 2015 as the publication date. You can also check the dates on the amazon reviews, which go back to 2007.  I don’t know if 2015 is the date of a reprint and it was out of print for awhile or what.  Ah, I think I know what's going on: the original was a hardback, and the 2015 version is paperback.  False advertising at its finest.